# Finding a check polynomial for a cyclic code

Tags: coding-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> $C$ is a binary cyclic $[7,4]$ code with generator matrix
>
> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> Write down a generating polynomial for $C$ and find a check polynomial $h$.

I find that the generating polynomial  is  $1 + u + u^{3}$

However, I am stuck on how to work out the check polynomial.

Perhaps $(1 + u + u^{3} ) ( 1 + au + bu^{2} + cu^{3} + du^{4}) = 0$

But how would one solve this? Or can I do long division, is fo can someone please show me how? \thanks

Comment: You may use the symbols $ if you put some LaTeX formulas.

Comment: The polynomial algebra of a binary cyclic code of length $n$ is done modulo $u^n+1$, so why don't you try and solve
$$(1 + u + u^{3} ) ( 1 + au + bu^{2} + cu^{3} + du^{4}) = 1+u^7$$ instead!

Comment: "Different" hint from that suggested by @JyrkiLahtonen  Instead of"solving" $$(1 + u + u^{3} ) ( 1 + au + bu^{2} + cu^{3} + du^{4}) = 1+u^7$$  (which implicitly suggests setting up linear equations etc for $a,b,c,d$ and then solving the system of linear equations), simply _divide_ $u^7+1$ by $1+u+u^3$ to get the parity-check polynomial!